# JQuery - nested loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a javascript that runs when the user change the dropdown list (Note: the change function, and the way we get the value of the dropdown list **work fine**), I have tested the function multiple times and found the issue is my second For-loop I am really stuck wondering why it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var username = prompt("Please enter your Username", "default");
        console.log("User: ",username);

        $.ajax({ url : "/memory/intro",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({"username": username}),
                contextType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
                success : function(){console.log("Done!");}});

        $("#lvl").change( function (){
                var diff = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
                console.log(diff); //Personal testing
                console.log(typeof(diff)); //Personal testing
                for(var i=0; i < diff; ++i){
                        var row;
                        row = $("<tr></tr>");
                        for(var x=0; i < diff; ++x) {
                                var col;
                                col = $("<div></div>");
                                col.addClass("card");
                                col.data("col", x);
                                row.append(col);
                        }
                        $("#cards").append(row);
                };

        });

});
```

Note: If we comment the second for-loop the whole code works fine and we append the "tr" and "div" with the class name

Comment: `for(var x=0; i < diff; ++x) {` should maybe be `for(var x=0; x < diff; ++x) {` (i.e. the stop condition depends on `x`, rather than `i`)

Comment: In your second loop you use `i < diff;`, shouldn't it be with an _x_ `x < diff;`

Comment: If this is the case, where change to `x` fix it, please consider delete this post as it is a simple typo issue

Comment: Thanks @nbrooks the code seemed so fine, I think I need glasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I didn't realise that I had `i < diff` on the second loop, thanks to @nbrooks

Answer (score 0):

second forloop try:

```
      for(var x=0; x < diff; ++x) {
            var col;
            col = $("<td></td>");
            col.addClass("card");
            col.data("col", x);
            row.append(col);
      }
```

So far as i know you shouldn't append a div to a tr, it causes errors  **(not js errors, but it are still markup errors)**

check [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/) if you want to be sure of this issue,